# Saved images to Gallery only display when phone is restarted - React-Native Android

Tags: image, android-gallery, react-native, react-native-fs

I am using the [File System API](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API) from the [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) library.

I request an image from the server, receive a base64 and I then save it to Pictures directory in the android fs.

I save the image like this:

```
var RNFetchBlob = require('react-native-fetch-blob').default;

const PictureDir = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.PictureDir;

getImageAttachment: function(uri_attachment, filename_attachment, mimetype_attachment) {

   return new Promise((RESOLVE, REJECT) => {

   // Fetch attachment
   RNFetchBlob.fetch('GET', config.apiRoot+'/app/'+uri_attachment)
   .then((response) => {

     let base64Str = response.data;

     let imageLocation = PictureDir+'/'+filename_attachment;

     //Save image
     fs.writeFile(imageLocation, base64Str, 'base64');
     console.log("FILE CREATED!!")

    }).catch((error) => {
    // error handling
    console.log("Error:", error)
  });
},
```

**Problem**
The image saves successfully but when I open the android's Gallery it is not visible. But when I turn off and on the Android emulator it is then visible in the Gallery.

**Question**
How can I view the image in the Android's Gallery without having to restart the emulator?

---

## Solution

---

I added this to the above method after the file is created:

```
RNFetchBlob.fs.scanFile([ { path : imageLocation, mime : mimetype_attachment } ])
.then(() => {
  console.log("scan file success")
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log("scan file error")
})
```

Thanks you @Xeijp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Android, to make an image visible in gallery you need to use 'media scanner' on that file. react-native-fetch-blob does provides an API for this

```
fs.scanFile(path_of_the_file)
```

[document](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#scanfilepathstringpromise-androi-only)

Answer (score 1):

the gallery gets it-s content from the media-database. the media scanner analyses the filesystem and updates the media db accordingly. It may need some time until the mediascanner has found your new image.

- you can ask the media scanner to analyse the directory where you have just saved the image as decribed in [how to run media scanner in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270789/how-to-run-media-scanner-in-android)
- or you can add the image to the mediadb yourself as decribed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38383848/519334

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but I was looking for a react-native-android solution.